# Rails has_many relation to all enum types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, relationship

I have 2 models: `Department` and `Station`. Station has 3 different `enum` types. User should have a possibility to select 1, 2 or 3 stations of different type using checkboxes. If a station is selected, a record in `Station` should be created.

Any idea how to do so?

Another words, it should be something like this:

```
class Department < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :stations, dependent: :destroy


class Station < ApplicationRecord
  enum type: { type1: 0, type2: 1, type3: 2 }
  belongs_to :department


_form.rb should be something like this:
  = f.association :stations, :as => :check_boxes, :collection => Station.types.keys
```

but of course it should be different.

Answer (score 0):

Since a `Department` can have at most one `Station` of each type, each type of station should have its own select input. These inputs should use names different from `stations` (maybe `station_type_1` etc.). Then you can create a hidden `stations` input and sync the selections.